# Несколько модальных окон на одной странице

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно, окно

На странице используется плагин The Modal (https://github.com/samdark/the-modal).

Есть кнопки такого вида:

```
<button data-id="01-content" class="map-b" type="button">Город Керчь</button>
<button data-id="02-content" class="map-b" type="button">Город Керчь</button>
```

и т.д.

Сейчас модальное окно открывается с таким кодом:
Само модальное окно:

```
    <div class="modal" id="test-modal">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
<h1>Это модальное окно</h1>
    </div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        // bind event handlers to modal triggers
        $('body').on('click', '.trigger', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#test-modal').modal().open();
        });

        // attach modal close handler
        $('.modal .close').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.modal().close();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ну естественно у кнопок добавлен класс `.trigger`. Просто здесь в вопросе он не прописан.

Всё это очень не удобно, потому как для каждого окна необходимо свой скрипт типа:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // bind event handlers to modal triggers
    $('body').on('click', '.trigger', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#test-modal').modal().open();
    });
```

Как привязать все окна к `data-id="`, атрибуты которых есть уже у кнопок, написав только один скрипт? Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В кнопке пишите `data-id="modal-window-1"` далее создаете модальное окно с `id="modal-window-1"` вместо `test-modal`. Открытие окна:

```
$('body').on('click', '.trigger', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).modal().open();
});
```

Но я делаю иначе, я просто храню содержимое модального окна и храню в аттрибутах html. Перед показом модального окна я строю html из json и наполняю этим html модальное окно. Это более удобный способ, если у Вас десятки и сотни модальных окон разного вида.